# firebase.firestore with react No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to user `firebase.firestore` with react. Here is how I initialize firebase.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './redux'

import Routes from './Routes'

import initFirebase from './initFirebase'

class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount () {
    initFirebase()
  }

  render () {
    return <Provider store={store}>
      {Routes}
    </Provider>
  }
}

export default App
```

And here is `initFirebase.js`

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import store from './redux'
import { setAuth } from './redux/actions/auth'

export default () => {
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyC1H97dDoIVurLdgHOGgfRRubrTmb3YkTo',
    authDomain: 'tree-of-life-ee870.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://tree-of-life-ee870.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'tree-of-life-ee870',
    storageBucket: 'tree-of-life-ee870.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: '861153906067'
  }
  firebase.initializeApp(config)

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    store.dispatch(setAuth(user))
  })
}
```

And here I try to use `firestore` like this

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import { SubmissionError } from 'redux-form'

import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

const db = firebase.firestore()
```

And get the error like this

```
Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
```

So what's the right way to initialize firebase in a react enviorment?

Answer (score 1):

You need initialize firebase before call `firebase.firestore()`
You can move

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

to `index.js` file.

Comment: Here's an example: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react/blob/master/example/src/App.jsx